# how to namespace in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

**I trying create a rails engine**

Content default

#### lib/abc_xyz.rb

```
require 'abc_xyz/engine'

module AbcXyz
end
```

#### abc_xyz/engine.rb

```
module AbcXyz
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace AbcXyz
  end
end
```

**But, i want nested it in a namespace, as below:**

#### lib/abc_xyz.rb

```
require 'abc/xyz/engine'

module Abc
  module Xyz
  end
end
```

#### abc/xyz/engine.rb

```
module Abc
  module Xyz
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace Abc
    end
  end
end
```

**but, rake abc:install:migrations not working for me**
. How to do it?

Comment: isolate_namespace Abc -> isolate_namespace Abc::Xyz

Comment: here is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71312087/1866752